# How to loop this python code multiple times

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, jpeg

I have a csv files with about 380 names listed like this below:

1. John Smith
2. Alert Johnson
3. Corey Johnson

and so on

I was able to import the first line and print it onto an image.
However, what I want to do is to be able to loop it and read all the names in the csv file, then print each one on an image. 
With 380 names, there should be 380 images with the names on it.

Basically I want to loop it until it reads all the names in the CSV file and save an image file for each name.

can someone help me on how to make it loop to read all the names on the csv?

```
    import PIL
    from PIL import ImageFont
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    import ImageFont, ImageDraw
    import csv
    import sys



    #opens csv file and reads the first line. Using rstrip to get rid of special character at end
    with open('Names.csv', 'rU') as f:
            for name in f:
        names = f.readline().rstrip()
            names2 = f.readline().rstrip()


    #font and size on local machine
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf", 150)


    #This is the text it will print.
    text = names


    #color of text = black
    tcolor = (255,0,0)


    #opens image in the same folder
    img = Image.open("Certificate.jpg") #opens image in the same folder


    #gets the height and width of the jpg
    width, height = Image.open(open("Certificate.jpg")).size


    #defining "draw" to draw onto image
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)


    #define variables x = width and y = height
    text_x, text_y = font.getsize(text)


    #find the middle of width using this equation and store into "x"
    x = (width - text_x)/2


    #find the middle of height using this equation and store into "y"
    y = (height - text_y)/2


    #calls "draw" and writes "text" using middle of jpg
    draw.text ( (x,y), text, font=font, fill=tcolor)


    #saves image
    img.save("test.jpg")
```

error I am getting:
File "full2.py", line 14, in 
     names = f.readline().rstrip()
valueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

I am able to use While in place of For. However, I do not know how to implement While to make it loop to keep reading a line and and print/save an image.

Comment: What if I told you that file objects were iterable and yield one line at a time when you do this `for name in f:` ... ?

Comment: When I try to use the for loop you mentioned, it will give me a "Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data"

Answer (score 2):

You should use a for loop to iterate over everyline, something like `for name in f:`

```
    import PIL
    from PIL import ImageFont
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    import ImageFont, ImageDraw
    import csv
    import sys



    #opens csv file and reads the first line. Using rstrip to get rid of special character   at end
    with open('Names.csv', 'rU') as f:
        for name in f: 
           #need to put all the statements below in this code block.
```

Comment: When I try to use the for loop you mentioned, it will give me a "Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data"

Comment: how would you want for me to share with you?

Comment: I have tried using while in this case instead of For and it works. However, I still do not know how to implement it to make it work as described above.

Comment: You should use "name" no "names" for the variable name, also all the operations applyed to the name must be with in the for loop block.